# Mini Batch Gradient Descent, adam and epochs

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am taking a course on Deep Learning in Python and I am stuck on the following lines of an example:

```
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
```

From the definitions I know, 
1 epoch = going through all training examples once to do one weight update.

`batch_size` is used in optimizer that divide the training examples into mini batches. Each mini batch is of size `batch_size`.

I am not familiar with adam optimization, but I believe it is a variation of the GD or Mini batch GD. Gradient Descent - has one big batch (all the data), but multiple epochs. Mini Batch Gradient Descent - uses multiple mini batches, but only 1 epoch.

Then, how come the code has both multiple mini batches and multiple epochs? 
Does epoch in this code has a different meaning then the definition above?

Answer (score 3):

Although the other answer basically already gives you the correct result, I would like to clarify on a few points you made in your post, and correct it.
The (commonly accepted) definitions of the different terms are as follows.

- **Gradient Descent (GD)**: Iterative method to find a (local or global) optimum in your function. Default Gradient Descent will *go through all examples* (one epoch), then update **once**.
- **Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)**: Unlike regular GD, it will *go through one example*, then **immediately update**. This way, you get a way higher update rate.
- **Mini Batching**: Since the frequent updates of SGD are quite costly (updating the gradients is kind of tedious to perform), and can lead to worse results in certain circumstances, it is helpful to aggregate *multiple (but not all) examples into one update*. This means, you would go through *n* examples (where *n* is your batch size), and **then update**. This will still result in multiple updates within one epoch, but not necessarily as many as with SGD.
- **Epoch**: One epoch simply refers to a pass through all of your training data. You can generally perform as many epochs as you would like.

One another note, you are correct about [ADAM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980). It is generally seen as a more powerful variant of vanilla gradient descent, since it uses more sophisticated heuristics (first order derivatives) to speed up and stabilize convergence.

Comment: I'm curious here. In SGD, are mini batches disjoint sets or could there be some intersect? Can keeping random say 30% of previous mini batch and adding 70% new sample improve learning?

Comment: To my knowledge there is little value in reusing samples across batches, given that the gradient signal likely already was given before. Unless you are doing a specific kind of negative sampling to get your batch (this is not directly used in SGD, but later derivations along the same line, such as contrastive learning).
AFAIK, there aren't any explicit empirical works demonstrating this understanding, but I've never heard anything like it before.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of **epoch** and **batch_size** seems correct.

Little more precision below.

An **epoch** corresponds to one whole training dataset sweep. This sweep can be performed in several ways.

- **Batch mode**: Gradient of loss over the whole training dataset is used to update model weights. One optimisation iteration corresponds to one epoch.
- **Stochastic mode**: Gradient of loss over one training dataset point is used to update model weights. If there are N examples in the training dataset, N optimisation iterations correspond to one epoch.
- **Mini-batch mode**: Gradient of loss over a small sample of points from the training dataset is used to update model weights. The sample is of size **batch_size**. If there are `N_examples` examples in the training dataset, `N_examples/batch_size` optimisation iterations correspond to one epoch.

In your case (`epochs=100`, `batch_size=32`), the `regressor` would sweep the whole dataset 100 items, with mini data batches of size 32 (ie. **Mini-batch mode**).

If I assume your dataset size is `N_examples`, the `regressor` would perform `N_examples/32` model weight optimisation iteration **per epoch**.

So for 100 epochs: `100*N_examples/32` model weight optimisation iterations.

All in all, having `epoch>1` and having `batch_size>1` are compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
"All in all, having epoch>1 and having batch_size>1 are compatible." doesn't seem compatible with the definitions (yours or mine, which are basically the same). Can you please explain how epochs = 100 and batch_size = 32 fits to one of the definitions (Batch mode, Stochastic mode or Mini-batch mode) ?

Comment: Hi @Eyal2000, I just added extra info on the answer

Comment: So, if I get it right, that means 1 epoch = an update after 1 batch_size examples. Is that right ?

Comment: @Eyal2000, no. 1 epoch = 1 complete dataset sweep = N_examples / batch_size updates. Just added extra info on answer.

Answer (score 1):

assume you have 3200 examples to train your model. Then 1 epoch = going through 3200 training examples, but do 100 times back propagation if you set batch_size=32.